# Iphone , receiving error during the Archiving

Tags: iphone, archive, linkage, beta-testing

I am currently trying to archive my application for testing but it generate these error :

> Ld "/Users/Simon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Photo_Gallery-fycuagscgzkapvglqzfytatmaxzm/ArchiveIntermediates/Photo Gallery/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Photo Gallery.build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/Photo Gallery.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Photo Gallery" normal armv6
>       cd "/Users/Simon/Desktop/Project/Photo Gallery"
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk "-L/Users/Simon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Photo_Gallery-fycuagscgzkapvglqzfytatmaxzm/ArchiveIntermediates/Photo Gallery/BuildProductsPath/Ad Hoc-iphoneos" "-L/Users/Simon/Desktop/Project/Photo Gallery/Photo Gallery/Admob" "-F/Users/Simon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Photo_Gallery-fycuagscgzkapvglqzfytatmaxzm/ArchiveIntermediates/Photo Gallery/BuildProductsPath/Ad Hoc-iphoneos" -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/Simon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Photo_Gallery-fycuagscgzkapvglqzfytatmaxzm/ArchiveIntermediates/Photo Gallery/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Photo Gallery.build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/Photo Gallery.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Photo Gallery.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework AssetsLibrary -lGoogleAdMobAds -o "/Users/Simon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Photo_Gallery-fycuagscgzkapvglqzfytatmaxzm/ArchiveIntermediates/Photo Gallery/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Photo Gallery.build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/Photo Gallery.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Photo Gallery"
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>     "_objc_getClassList", referenced from:
>         _GTMGetStackAddressDescriptorsForAddresses in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GTMStackTrace.o)
>     "_UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification", referenced from:
>         +[GADObjectPrivate initialize] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADObjectPrivate.o)
>         +[GADObjectPrivate appDidFinishLaunching:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADObjectPrivate.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSError", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADRequestError in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADRequestError.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADMError in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADMError.o)

Does anyone see these error before? It looks like some linking problem ....

Comment: Something's pretty messed up in your project. It's trying to link x86 simulator frameworks into your arm device build.

Comment: which Xcode and iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: If I had a clue why, I'd add it as an answer, but I don't. The command you show is the linker trying to include libraries that run in the simulator on OS X into your app for real devices. I've no idea why, but that's very wrong. If you don't have any other way to debug this (editing project files is painful and error prone) I'd probably think about recreating the project file from scratch.

Comment: I WILL TRY THAT， MAYBE THAT IS ONLY WAY

Comment: I have followed smpakes suggestion to create the new project... It does make the different. Now I have the ipa ready for testing.